# How to step a rotary switch by using LUA script

Tags: lua

I am trying to solve a problem with LUA scripting of rotary switches in helios.
I am trying to be able to move the rotary in both directions , either increase or decrease. At the moment I can only do one direction at a time. I have managed to be able to go either way but it only works if you complete one direction before changing to the other. This is not good enough , I want to be able to change direction , increase or decrease at any point.

I use separate buttons to initiate either a step up or a step down, the scripting is shown below. If I do not fully complete the stepping in one direction , eg increase but try to reverse it part way then the decrease script does not take note of the actual position that the rotary as reached but starts the decrease from the position of the rotary that was commanded by the last time the decrease was used.

To explain more clearly:-  Rotary at position 0 ...press increase two times rotary steps from 0 to 1 then 2.....Press decrease .....rotary steps from 0 to 7
I want it to step from 2 back to 1

An example of LUA scripting being used for a eight position rotary displaying digits 0 to 7

Rotary INC Button

```lua
rotary = rotary or 1

if rotary < 8 then

rotary = rotary + 1

else

rotary = 1

end
return rotary
```

Rotary DEC Button

```lua
rotary = rotary or 1

if rotary > 1 then

rotary = rotary - 1

else
rotary = 8

end

return rotary
```

Can you suggest any changes to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What does "at any point" mean? When can you currently change direction? It sounds like queuing the button presses and then working through the queue might be what you want.

Comment: Can you provide more details from the script? "script does not take note of the actual position" states that you have variable declaration-usage problem, or other parts of the script manipulates it

Comment: Upload your full script

Comment: "at any point " means I want to be able to change from increasing to decreasing without having to continue to the last step.

Comment: I use two separate scripts controlled by two separate inputs and I have shown them in there entirety. I think the problem is that they are separate and not linked in any way but I have no idea how to do this. I should state that I have very little knowledge of LUA and have only reached this stage with help from the Falcon BMS forum. I am hoping by asking here to achieve what I want to do from this script.

Comment: IMP1  thank you for edit I tried to do that but found  this site very unfriendly for inexperienced users. I see you are in Leeds, the city where I was born and lived for 60 years, now in Scotland for past 20 years...thanks again David

Comment: You must provide more detailed information to help you. Which version of lua you use: eLua, 5.14, LuaJIT 2.0.5...? What type of device and enironment you use: Embedded Linux, Windows, Elinos, OpenWrt, ESP8266,...? How these scripts are executed if button is pressed: `/bin/lua buttonup.lua`, or from another lua script like `loadfile('buttonup')()`?